# Function not calling on sortable update in angular 10

Tags: angularjs

```
  activateSort(){     
 
    /* let isLoadedInCard = false; */
    $(".group-items" ).sortable({
      containment: "document",
      opacity: 0.6,
      scroll: true,
      items: ".group-item",
      placeholder: "item-placeholder",
      tolerance: "pointer",
      refreshPositions: true,
      connectWith: '.group-items',
      forcePlaceholderSize: true ,
      cursor: "move",
      delay: 150,
      distance: 5,
      hoverClass: "highlight",
      dropOnEmpty: true,
      start: function(e, ui) {        
        ui.placeholder.css("visibility", "visible");
        ui.placeholder.css("background-color", "#cccccc");
        ui.placeholder.css("display", "block"); 
    },
    
    update: function( e,ui) {
 
       this.handleSearch();
    }
 
    }
    
    }).disableSelection();
   
  
  }
```

this.handleSearch();  This function not triggering on update.

Function not calling while i use drag and drop method.

```
update: function( e,ui) {
      console.log("working");
}
```

Console.log is working but not able to trigger function

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning `handleSearch` to $scope:

```js
$scope.handleSearch = function () {
    // body of handle search
}
```

Then in `sortable` you can use:

```js
update: function( e,ui) {
         $scope.handleSearch();
        }
```